# Apex synchronous callouts in Salesforce triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

I have a Salesforce trigger that gets fired whenever the firstName field in the Application object gets updated.
Once it happens, I want to make an Http call and get the response to be used in another function in the trigger right after the callout. So, the callout should be synchronous, as I need the response to be used in another function.

(I know that for asynchronous functions I should use the @future annotation, but I want to make a synchronous callout.)

Does anyone have any idea?

Here is the trigger:

```
trigger TestAppTrigger on Application__c (after update) {

    private Boolean testVal = false;
    
    for (Application__c app: Trigger.new) {
     
     
        Application__c oldApp = Trigger.oldMap.get(app.Id);
        if (oldApp.firstName != app.firstName){ 
                                  
           testVal = TestAppTriggerClass.Test('10');

           //I need to take the response and pass it in to the following function:

           TestAppTriggerClass.Test2(testVal);           
    
        }       
        
    }      
}
```

And here is the class that holds the functions:

```
public class TestAppTriggerClass {

     
   public static Boolean Test(String studentId) {
         
        Boolean test;
                   
        //sending the http request and receiving the response
        List<Object> responseArray= HelperClass.httpFunction(studentId); 

        if (responseArray.isEmpty()) test = false;         
        else test = true;   
     
        return test;
     }


   public static void Test2(Boolean testVal) {
     //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce does not allow us to make synchronous callouts from triggers.

You need to do this async, there is no way around it.

Though instead of having your trigger call `Test1()` and then `Test2()`...
there's nothing stopping you from having your trigger call `Test1()` (which is the method that makes the callout, the one that must be asynchronous/run in a different transaction)
and then `Test1()` internally calling `Test2()`

Comment: The reason why is that long callouts causes database contention, so we are prohibited from doing this in order to make access to resources more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried what you suggested. However, because Test2() is also an asynchronous function, when I call it internally, I get an error saying it is not possible to call a future method inside another!

Comment: @RoseMirzaei Was `Test2()` always `@future`? The example you provided doesn't indicate that it is. Since we can't read minds or see your screen, it's important to provide details and be accurate here. It's very difficult to provide accurate, useful answers otherwise. You should edit your question to address that. For now, about all I can say is that `Test2()` should not be `@future` (it'll still be run in the same async context as `Test1()`, provided you call it from `Test1()`). If there is a reason to do it in two separate async contexts, then you'd want to use `Queueable` instead.

Comment: You are right, I should have mentioned that Test2() is also a future method. I used the Queueable classes and now the problem is solved! Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.